# How do i pass strings from one page to another in this C# app using a button?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my MainPage.xaml: area and btu have values inside the button function and I changed them to strings.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)        
{       
    ...

    area.ToString();

    btu.ToString();

    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SolutionPage.xaml?msg1=" + area, UriKind.Relative));
     NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SolutionPage.xaml?msg2=" + btu, UriKind.Relative));

}
```

then, in page1.xaml, i have:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    string msg1 = "";
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("msg1", out msg1))
    {
        textBlock1.Text = String.Format("Area:{0}", msg1);
    }
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    string msg2 = "";
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("msg2", out msg2))
    {
        textBlock2.Text = String.Format("BTU:{0}", msg2);
    }
}
```

The problem is that only textBlock1 change (Area).
What should i do to pass btu.ToString() to textBlock2.text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the navigation request once, and append both values to it.

```
string url = string.Format("/SolutionPage.xaml?msg1={0}&msg2={1}", area.toString(), btu.toString());
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative));
```

And in your `OnNavigatedTo`, only call the base version once.

Comment: thank you but it should be(new Uri, Urikind.Relative)) without parenthesis in url

Comment: Ah yes, it should be new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative). Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

you only get to make one call to `Navigate`.  So you're going to need to pass both of those params to the navigate call, like

```
new Uri( "/SolutionPAge.xaml?msg1=blah&msg2=blah", UriKind.Relative);
```

and then parse it apart in one call to `OnNavigatedTo`

if only one changes, just pass only one of those values in the query string.

Comment: blah must be a variable, if i put area instead blah, the answer is Area:area, it takes area as text, no as the variable. i tried concatenation but doesn't work, but thank you